# How to select documents with specific elements in MongoDB with PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, select, count, find

I have the following structure of a mongo document:

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("4fba2558a0787e53320027eb"),
 "replies": {
    "0": {
      "email": ObjectId("4fb89a181b3129fe2d000000"),
      "sentDate": "2012-05-21T11: 22: 01.418Z",
      "type": "one"
    } 
    "1": {
     "email": ObjectId("4fb89a181b3129fe2d000000"),
     "sentDate": "2012-05-21T11: 22: 01.418Z",
      "type": "two"
    } 
    "2" ....
 }

}
```

How do I select only documents containing only specific type of replies, for example "type":"one"?
Thank you!

Comment: can you explain this schema?  why are replies structured with number keys rather than, say, an array which would look more natural and might be a lot simpler to deal with.

Comment: this is how mongo inserts them in the document. is there a way to get rid of the key? would be easier for counting?

Comment: Read this, this was solved before :-)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901977/mongodb-nested-array-search

Comment: That's what I was getting at - the problem is only solved for a different structure/schema.  It's not solvable for this structure generically.

Comment: indeed, and I can't change the schema at this moment...

Answer (score 0):

It simply worked like this, first time I was trying to do a group on it:

```
$cursor = $db->foo->find(
    array('replies.type' => 'one'), array('replies.sentDate')
);
```

Maybe it will help others like me. The keys "0", "1" ... have no effect.

Answer (score -1):

Look to `$elemMatch` in mongo documentation I think it will help. 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all

You may try this:

```
t.find({replies: {$elemMatch: { "type": "one" } } });
```

Comment: you will find that this does not match anything.